# Como verificar se existe uma função no Titanium Studio?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Eu preciso verificar se em uma View existe um evento OnClick que executa a função teste

```
if($.minhaview.propriedade == 'teste'){


   alert("existe um evento onClick com o valor teste");


}
```

Comment: Pode dar um pouco mais de contexto? O que é a `propriedade`? E onde a função `teste` é definida? Ela está no escopo quando esse `if` roda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você adicionou a um elemento a propriedade `onclick`, pode testa-la, por exemplo:

```
if ($.minhaview.onclick) { 
  // faça algo...
}
```

Porém se você adicionou o evento com `addEventListener('click', evento)` ai a resposta é: não é possível verificar se há um evento neste elemento.

O observer que gerencia eventos dos elementos no javascript apenas permite adicionar e remover eventos, mas não expõe a lista de eventos.

Porém é possível modificar esse comportamento modificando o protótipo de eventos, assim como o jQuery faz.

Você poderia criar uma forma de armazenar em alguma propriedade do objeto a lista de eventos contidas nele. Mas por padrão a especificação da W3C não prevê essa exposição.

Answer (score 0):

Se você só quer testar se a variável já tem o valor de uma função atribuido, pode usar a função typeof.

```
if(typeof $.minhaview.propriedade === 'function')
{
  // ...
}
```